# What will happen if I uninstall python to reinstall it?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have badly installed python on my computer and I would like to uninstall it and then reinstall it. But How will it affect my computer ? I have already installed some modules and I'm using VSCode. Will I have to reconfigure all VSCode ? And will I keep my modules ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: if you uninstall python you lose all the installed modules that are stored in the global `Lib`, also virt envs need to be created again unless you use the exact same python version, but you have to modify the `activate` scripts for the new location, better to just install them all again in a new virt env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your installation path the second time is exactly the same as the first time, it won't make much of a difference. But you'll need to re-download those third-party libraries, since they were removed.

As for vscode, if you install it in the same path, there is no need to reconfigure it. You can install many python environments, just choose one for vscode via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>　--> `Python: Select Interpreter`.

In fact, you can use a [virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_creating-environments), which will be more convenient.